# Transparent movie with video format qtrle unplayable in QuickTime

Tags: ffmpeg, manim

I use the python library Manim to generate mathematical animations. I want to use the animations in Keynote presentations. Manim has the option to produce movie clips with a transparent background. Unfortunately, QuickTime won't play the files generated by Manim. Here's the metadata for a file produced by Manim

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:01:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6635 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), argb(progressive), 1280x960, 6632 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 qtrle
```

Ideally, I would want to use ffmpeg to turn these files into movie clips with transparent background which are playable in QuickTime. Can this be done?

As a work around, I imported the files into Final Cut Pro and exported them again using Apple Pro Res 4444, but this resulted in huge file sizes.

Comment: Why does it have to be playable in QuickTime? Why not use a more capable player?

Comment: @Ilogan I want to use the animations in Keynote. I assume it is the same engine as QuickTime.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It seems that qtlre is no longer supported by quicktime and it seems that the only solution is to use prores codecs that end up in huge files. I am not 100% of my claims, so please take them with a grain of salt.